# Converting $(4,-4{\sqrt3}, 6)$ from rectangular to cylindrical coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems

I'm getting the wrong answer for $\theta$. What am I doing wrong?

$$(4,-4{\sqrt3}, 6)$$
$$r =\sqrt{4^4 + (-4\sqrt{3})^2} = 8$$
$$z = 6$$
$$\tan\theta=\frac{-4\sqrt{3}}{4}$$
$$\tan\theta=-\sqrt{3}$$
$$\theta=\arctan-\sqrt{3}$$
$$\theta=-1.047$$

But the right answer is $\frac{5\pi}{3}$, which is $5.236$. 
Where is my mistake?

Comment: Your answer has the right $\tan$ but is in the wrong quadrant.

Comment: Looks like the answer $5.236 = -1.047+2\pi$. What convention for the range of $\theta$ does your homework usually use? $[0,2\pi)$ or $(-\pi,\pi]$?

Comment: @peterwhy: The range of $\theta$ is $[0,2\pi)$. I don't understand how you got to 5.236. How I am supposed to plug in the numbers on the calculator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have said, you have found the correct quadrant for the tangent. But you have found a $\theta$ from $\arctan$ which is outside $[0,2\pi)$. Back to you step,

$$\begin{align}
\tan \theta =& -\sqrt3\\
\theta =& n\pi + \arctan \left(-\sqrt3\right) &\text{for integer }n\\
=& n\pi - \frac{\pi}{3}\\
=& \frac{(3n-1)\pi}{3}
\end{align}$$

As you have correctly figured out, $\theta$ is in the fourth quadrant. This eliminates the possible values of $\theta$ to $2n\pi-\dfrac{\pi}{3} = \dfrac{(6n-1)\pi}{3}$. Secondly, $0\le \theta<2\pi$, so

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
0\le&\frac{(6n-1)\pi}{3}&<2\pi\\
0\le&\frac{6n-1}{3}&<2\\
0\le&6n-1&<6\\
\frac{1}{6}\le&n&<\frac76
\end{array}$$

and so $n=1$. $\theta = \dfrac{(6n-1)\pi}{3} = \dfrac{5\pi}{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your point is in the fourth region in the $xy$-plane where $\tan\theta$ is negative, so $\theta=\frac{5\pi}{3}$.

Comment: OP used the right fourth quadrant. His/her answer differs by $2\pi$ only.

Comment: I get it that it's in the fourth quadrant, but how did you get to $5\pi/3$? How did you calculate it?

Comment: Draw a right triangle in the plane with its hypotenuse is the distance from origin to your point and angle $\theta$ is measured  from the $x$-axis to the hypothenuse in the clockwise direction (which gives a negative value for the angle). In your case it is actually the angle $\frac{\pi}{3}$ from the $x$-axis in negative direction which coresponds also $2\pi-\frac{\pi}{3}=\frac{5\pi}{3}$.